# @use '@angular/material' causes build failure in Angular .sass file

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I am trying to use Angular Material's elevation function in my component's .sass file.
However when using `@use '@angular/material' as mat` I am getting

```
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
/payment-categories.component.sass:17:100: ERROR: Unterminated string token
```

Here's entire .sass file I'm using (the component is a grid with mat-cards):

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat

.category-card-container
  display: grid
  gap: 10px
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(150px, 1fr))
  @media only screen and (min-width: 481px)
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(150px, 1fr))

.category-card:hover
  @include mat.elevation(9)
  cursor: pointer
  
.chart
  margin: 5px

.card-divider
  margin-top: 10px
  margin-bottom: 10px
```

I did some research and managed to find a more detailed error message:

```
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
80 │ @forward './md-comp-sheetEntity-bottom' as md-comp-sheetEntity-bottom-*;
   │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  @material\tokens\_index.scss 80:1                                            @use
  node_modules\@material\data-table\_data-table-theme.scss 45:1                @use
  node_modules\@material\data-table\_data-table-header-cell.scss 35:1          @use
  @material\data-table\_data-table.scss 40:1                                   @use
  node_modules\@angular\material\table\_table-theme.scss 3:1                   @use
  node_modules\@angular\material\core\density\private\_all-density.scss 30:1   @forward
  @angular\_index.scss 18:1                                                    @use
  src\app\components\payment-categories\payment-categories.component.sass 1:1  root stylesheet
```

But it didn't help at all

Comment: are you using a default material theme? if so, is it included in the `angular.json` file ?, what do you have under the `styles.scss`?

Comment: I haven't changed anything with material themes.
styles.sass has only:
`body, html
  width: 100%
  padding-bottom: max(12px, env(safe-area-inset-bottom))
  margin: 0 !important
`